# Why ImageView disappears in the middle of animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I am trying to use Property Animation to demo a falling star animation but failed. My demo is simple:
1.  Create a MainActivity which has a start button.
2.  Click the start button to start the MeteorActivity
3.  MeteorActivity has a relative layout content view containing a simple star ImageView which locates at the middle/center of the layout.
4.  In MeteorActivity’s onResume method, I start the property animation to change the ImageView’s “top” property from 0 to 1000.
The problem is that the star is falling fine from the top edge until it reaches its original position (middle of the layout). It disappears!!!! Can anybody please help on this?

MeteorActivity:

```
public class MeteorActivity extends Activity implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meteor);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startMeteor();
}

private void startMeteor() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.starImageView);
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(imageView, "top", 0, 1000);
    anim.setDuration(10000);
    anim.addUpdateListener(this);
    anim.start();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.starImageView);
    Log.d("ImageView:Height:", Integer.valueOf(imageView.getTop()).toString());
}
```

}

Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/starImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/meteor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you share the layout xml code ?

Comment: layout xml added, thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please update your layout with below i posted, let's try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/starImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

One more point when you need to stop the animation let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks, now it does not disappear any more, but it starts falling from its original position. I want it to fall from 0. Can you please help again?

Comment: Tried several modifications but failed. Strongly doubt whether property animation is able to do it. Maybe I can be better off with manual onDraw repainting.